# paypal sandbox - can't change password

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I try to change the password of my paypal sandbox test account, for security, it asks me to enter either a full credit card number or full bank account number. It gives me the last few digits of these accounts, as in the image below:

[image]

So the basic problem is this credit card number and bank account number were auto-created by the sandbox when I created these account. I have no idea what either of these numbers actually are. Here's what I have tried:

- tried creating a new credit card from a valid test card #, tried making it primary. That all worked, but when I go back to the verification screen, my new card doesn't show up -- it's just the same default one.
- tried googling to find what that test credit card number, or the test bank account numbers are. No dice.
- For the security challenge, tried choosing secret questions instead of account numbers. There's a glitch in paypal and it won't even take me to that screen, still takes me to cc/bank.
- Tried resetting password from "forgot password", but the email never comes, because it's sandbox.

I just want to change my password. How can I do this?

Comment: The card data is available under developer.paypal.com > Applications > Sandbox accounts > Profile > Funding sources

Comment: Doesn't work for old accounts. Old accounts aren't listed anymore in new developer->sandbox page. To import an account you have to know the password. I wrote to technical help maybe they will import it for me without password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change your sandbox account password from developer.paypal.com.

1. Go to [developer.paypal.com](https://developer.paypal.com/home/) and log in
2. Click "Applications"
3. Click "Sandbox accounts"
4. Select one of your test accounts, then click "Profile"
5. Click "Change password"
6. Enter a new password, then click "Save"

[image: Profile Screenshot]

[image: PW change]

> NOTE: If you're trying to change the password and see the error message "please try again" after clicking "Save", make sure the new password has these characteristics:

- between 8 and 20 characters
- mix of uppercase, lowercase, letters, numbers, and symbols

Hope this helps! Let me know if you run into any issues.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and sorry for my delay in getting back to you.

Comment: I emailed support and got a call back (surprised). They said passwords cannot be changed on sandbox accounts. You can delete the account and create a new one. With regards to the screenshot above, like @T4NK3R said, no matter what you will get a "Please try again". They said this has been escalated, so hopefully they will either add the feature back in or remove the "option" to change the password since it no longer is supported.